# Grab values from elements on button click React/Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to grab the values from the elements I am mapping through here:

```
  {userInfo.children &&
    userInfo.children.map((child, key) => {
      const { name, dob, gender } = child;
      return (
        <div key={key}>
          <h3>{name}</h3>
          <h3>{dob}</h3>
          <h3>{gender}</h3>

          <button onClick={removeChild}>Remove</button>
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

This is my function:

```
const removeChild = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.parentNode); };
```

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odjfq.png)

So when I click on the button I want to grab the name, dob, and gender of the one being clicked.

The only way I know how to do it is with `event.target.parentNode.firstChild` but I know this isn't good practice since if I were to add another element before `<h3>{name}</h3>` it'll mess everything up.

I also don't think I could grab it by className or id. I've tried it but it gives me an array of all the data instead of the one clicked on.

Please let me know if I need more details or if this is repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the child object to the remove child method to do that.

```
<button onClick={(e) => removeChild(e, child)}>Remove</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried doing that but in a different way which didn't work. This works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way for you to do this is to make a separate `Child` component instead of rendering just the html elements. Also you should store the `userInfo` in some form of state. One of the purposes of React is to avoid having to use direct DOM manipulation and to manage data in a store rather than just in the DOM and then manipulating it that way.

Instead, create a `Child` component that consists of

```
<div key={key}>
          <h3>{name}</h3>
          <h3>{dob}</h3>
          <h3>{gender}</h3>

          <button onClick={removeChild}>Remove</button>
        </div>
```

Then in this component, you can pass props, even implement state if you want to but you don't have to. You can now pass all of the `child` data down to the component, as well as `removeChild`.

```
{userInfo.children &&
    userInfo.children.map((child, key) => {
      return (
        <Child key={key} child={child} removeChild={removeChild}/>
      );
    })}
```

*Child.js*

```
const Child = ({child, removeChild, key}) =>{
  const {name, dob, gender} = child
  <div key={key}>
    <h3>{name}</h3>
    <h3>{dob}</h3>
    <h3>{gender}</h3>
   <button onClick={()=>removeChild(key)}>Remove</button>
  </div>

}
```

And in your parent component here is the updated `removeChild`.

```
const removeChild = (index) =>{
  var dummy = {...userInfo}
  dummy.children = dummy.children.filter((x, i)=>i!==index)
  //below is where you use hooks or class state or whatnot 
  //to update userInfo to reflect the new children list
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you mean have userInfo be part of a useState for example? Currently it is, i'm just passing it down from another component.

Also, what is the removeChild function that you updated doing exactly and how is it different?

Comment: @SavedCity yeah i meant have it in state, useState is a great way to manage it. My removeChild is different because it updates state rather than manipulating the DOM directly; a big part of the foundation/intention of React. Moving forward if you’re going to use React you should write your code this way otherwise you might as well use regular JS.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm aware of how React works though in that sense. I wasn't trying to manipulate the DOM in the way you're thinking. I was needing those element values to pass it to my function in order for the method I was wanting to implement delete some data. 
If you're curious, I am using firebase and there's a method where, in order to remove a nested object in an array field, I need to pass all those specific values in that object.